# Python: TimeDate Issue

Tags: python, date, time, strptime

I have been making a small countdown timer to a specific time, but it seems to have a issue of negative days. Example:

```
s1 = '14:00:00'
s2 = str(current_time)
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s1, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s2, FMT)
print tdelta
>>>-1 day, 22:34:23
```

`Current_time` is my System time

How can I remove the `-1 day`? Neither string (`s1` or `s2`) has days, so its making this day figure within the `tdelta` variable calculation.

Comment: If you use 'current_time' object. Why don't you use that in the substraction? (Now you do: object => string => parse back to object)

Comment: According to the spec (https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) returns a time object which holds the date and time. Substracting a date and a time will probably go wrong.

Comment: Please provide an example for `current_time`.

Comment: `now = datetime.now()`

`hour = str(now.hour)`

`mi = str(now.minute)`

`ss = str(now.second)`

`current_time = hour + ':' + mi + ':' + ss` That is the code for the current_time @whereswalden

Comment: Perhaps you want to subtract `s1` from `s2`, not the other way around, the way you have it now (endtime - starttime instead of starttime - endtime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the day the target time should be (like 2014,8,1) use it:

```
import datetime
target_time = datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 1, 14, 0, 0)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
time_to_go = target_time - now
print(time_to_go)
```

If the target time is today, you can just change hour, minute and second and leave the rest from todays date:

```
import datetime
target_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=14, minute=0, second=0, microsecond = 0)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
time_to_go = target_time - now
print(time_to_go)
```

If the target_time is before the current time, the timedelta object tracks the negative time by using negative days and positive seconds that are decreasing and thus increase the negative difference and thus the time distance to the target_time.

If you always want to track the time to a given hour, regardless of day, use:

```
import datetime
target_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=14, minute=0, second=0, microsecond = 0)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if target_time < now:
    target_time += datetime.timedelta(1)
time_to_go = target_time - now
print(time_to_go)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the issue remains. I should have added that the countdown runs daily to the same time. For example: `s1` will always stay at 2PM. Once the countdown reaches that time, it need to then calculate the countdown time for the next day. I think this is the overall issue, its still calculating the same day (hence the negative) so how would i tell it to then calculate from the next days date?

Comment: Got it. The -1 in days is the result of the timedelta being measured with negative day and positive seconds, which adds up to negative seconds.

Comment: Added the answer to your question.